# hibernate oracle rownum issue

Tags: oracle, hibernate

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
   select * 
   from tableA 
   where ColumnA = 'randomText' 
   ORDER BY columnL ASC 
) WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
```

on execution of this query, due to some Oracle optimization, the query takes about 14 minutes to execute . If I remove the where clause , the query executes in seconds. most of the columns of the table have indexes on them, including the ones mentioned above. I do not have much flexibility on the structure of the query as I use hibernate.

This query returns results instantly too, with the correct result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
   select * 
   from tableA, 
        dual 
   where ColumnA = 'randomText' 
   ORDER BY columnL ASC
) WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
```

is there something I can do, using hibernate?

UPDATE: I use EntityManager.createQuery(), and I use setMaxResults(25) and setFirstResult() too. the query above is what hibernate's query looks like, upon observation of logs

Comment: Could you please post HQL itself? Does your original query contain joins on collections? Also the mapping itself would be useful as well.

Comment: Can you provide the explain plans for the two queries?

Comment: @ctapobep  http://pastebin.com/qjzu5HKc is the HQL . as you can see, there are no joins.

Comment: @JensSchauder for query with no join and where clause, explain plan :http://static.inky.ws/image/2857/image.jpg 
for query with join on DUAL, explain plan :
http://static.inky.ws/image/2858/image.jpg
for query with no join but where clause, explain plan :
http://static.inky.ws/image/2859/image.jpg

Comment: the last one is no join and no where clause, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the explain plans exactly matched to your queries, but it seems oracle using a different index for the two queries.

Can you create an index containing `columnA` and `columnL`?

If you have an index only containing `columnA`, you MIGHT be able to drop that without a large effect on performance of other queries.

An alternative would be to add a hint to use the index used in the faster query. But this would require you to use native sql.

Comment: the query is build dynamically, so columnL could potentially be any column of the table. hence composite index are not a feasible solution.

Answer (score -2):

this means you are using hibernate/jpa? If so, I guess you are using the `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()` to create the query? Try removing your where-restriction and use the `.setMaxResults(25)` on the `Query` instead.

Anyways, why do you need the outer-select? Wouldn't

```
select * 
from tableA 
where ColumnA = 'randomText' 
AND ROWNUM <= 25
ORDER BY columnL ASC
```

produce the desired results?

Comment: without the outer select rownum does not honor the order by

Comment: then try using it without the outer select and with the setMaxResults. I would be really surprised if this didnt work.

Comment: @Korgen I use EntityManager.createQuery(), and I use setMaxResults(25) and setFirstResult() too. the query above is what hibernate's query looks like, upon observation of logs.

Comment: @user1677819 that's some valueable information which should've gone into your question ;-\

Comment: @Korgen I do not have flexibility to put Rownum in the where clause as putting the actual query in the subquery is what hibernate does.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/post/on-rownum-and-limiting-results

When you use `order by` and want to retrieve the top-N results, SQL like this **would not** work:
`select * from my_table order by column_1 where rownum < N;`
This is because `rownum` is evaluated **before** sorting, not after. Oracle will pick random N rows and sort them, not sort and then pick N. This difference is often neglected.

Comment: Actually if you check class `OracleDialect`, this is handled well in the implementation of Hibernate. That's why the SQL in the OP is like that. There's nothing to change there.